# How do I seamlessly blend in one rendered image with a background video?

Tags: rendering, shaders, compositing-nodes

I have this render of an animation of a hanging head which I composite on top of a video using *Alpha Over* node. It looks like the face has just been slapped onto the video, and I am unsure what exactly is missing to blend the image together with the video. Is there some compositing trick or technique I need to employ to seamlessly blend them in? It probably is the edges of the image that makes it look very fake.

[image]

[image]

Comment: maybe blur the background image? (or the foreground)

Comment: Lighting. If the illumination and shadows of the head don't match the background it won't integrate well

Comment: To add to what Duarte has said, you may want to put the background on top of the head, using Fresnel for alpha. It won't be physically accurate, but be more realistic then no blend at all of the edge.

Comment: Make sure all sizes are realistic, match the source camera's focal length, f-stop, and depth of field focus distance

Comment: thank you guys for your inputs. btw @MarkusvonBroady this fresnel thing sounds interesting, can you show me exactly how? i'll accept it as answer if ever you can post it. currently i'm doing it as moonboots recommended blurring the background since i have already rendered it out.

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie I'm not sure about the best possible technique, but the general idea is very basic: if you e.g. render the face alone, with the shader just displaying the fresnel, then you have just a white border, based on the geometry of the head, and you can use it as a mask in the compositor to overlay the background image on top of the head. You probably still need to adjust the opacity to reduce the effect (and reduce it a lot, you're not supposed to see the image on top, just tint the skin near silhouette very slightly) and that's it.